# Matplotlib install issues. Pip Centos - Freetype "Missing" when it is installed

Tags: django, matplotlib, centos, virtualenv, freetype

I am using a virtualenv for a django setup. I am trying to build a view that pulls data from logs and then graphs the data. Eventually I would like to have this real-time and live. If you have any recommendations on other solutions that would suit my project best, please do not hesitate to include them in the comment fields below.

I have attempted to install matplotlib from pip using pip install matplotlib.

I receive the following message:

```
* The following required packages can not be built:
* freetype
```

I then validated that it was installed

```
yum install freetype 
Package freetype-2.3.11-14.el6_3.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

I then found that there is a python-matplotlib which is an older version .99. However, I want to keep this inside of the virtual environment and not system wide.

```
find / -name *freetype*
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/f/d2807dcfe3762c0b9f8ef1d9bf0f05788e73282a-freetype-2.3.11-14.el6_3.1-  x86_64
/usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.3.22
/usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6
/usr/share/doc/freetype-2.3.11
```

I searched all over stackoverflow and only saw solutions for ubuntu which did not transfer over to centos.

Thank you for your time,
John

Answer (score 9):

pip is going to compile matlibplot on your local machine, so you'll need freetype development headers installed as well.

CentOS 6+, Fedora, etc.:

```
$ sudo yum -y install freetype freetype-devel libpng-devel
```

On older operating systems (e.g. CentOS 5), you may run into a more specific freetype versioning issue with newer releases of matlibplot. If you're version agnostic, sticking with a legacy 1.3.x release will negate these dependency issues:

```
$ pip install matplotlib==1.3.1
```

Please note, you may need to downgrade your numpy to 1.8 in order to make matplotlib 1.3 work.

```
$ pip install numpy==1.8
```

Good luck!

Comment: Worked for me on CentOS 5

Answer (score 2):

I have just had a similar (albeit not exactly the same) situation. I'll write it up here as this page comes up among the first search results.

- CentOS 5
- `pip install matplotlib` complains about `freetype`
- Both `freetype` and `freetype-devel` are installed.
- `~/.pip/pip.log` provides the explanation of the problem. There is the line:

  `freetype: no  [Requires freetype2 2.3 or later.  Found 2.2.1.]`
- Obviously, the solution is either to upgrade `freetype` or downgrade `matplotlib`.
- The second is easier (assuming I am OK with the older version).
- `pip install matplotlib==1.3.1` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

On the matplotlib installation, this is what I did. Not sure if this is going to help you. Just followed the steps here:
http://pkgs.org/centos-6/centos-x86_64/python-matplotlib-0.99.1.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html

I did not use pip, btw and have CentOS 6.4.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me in two different situations, see if yours is one of them:

1. freetype was installed, but not in the `$PATH` yet. Just exiting the shell and starting a new one fixed this.
2. I was building matplotlib from source, and trying to build from the `master` branch. After I switched to `v1.3.x` it correctly detected freetype.