# pip install error, freetype and libpng missing (Windows)

Tags: windows, pip, installation, freetype2

I have downloaded a repo from github and am trying to install the requirements in a venv. It's telling me freetype and libpng libraries are missing, so I went to the websites and installed them. However I'm still being told they're missing. (after restarting of course)

Here's the error in the log:

```
Collecting matplotlib==2.2.2
  Using cached matplotlib-2.2.2.tar.gz (37.3 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\programming\python\example programs\deepfake\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\garym\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ppn3h81t\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\garym\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ppn3h81t\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\garym\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ppn3h81t\matplotlib\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\garym\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ppn3h81t\matplotlib\
    Complete output (61 lines):
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [2.2.2]
                    python: yes [3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019,
                            19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]]
                  platform: yes [win32]

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [not found. pip may install it below.]
          install_requires: yes [handled by setuptools]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype
                            (freetype2\ft2build.h) could not be found.  You may
                            need to install the development package.]
                       png: no  [The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be
                            found.  You may need to install the development
                            package.]
                     qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
            toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                    macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                    qt5agg: no  [PySide2 not found; PyQt5 not found]
                    qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
                   gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
                 gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                    gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                     tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                            Tk]
                     wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                       gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
                 windowing: yes [installing]

    OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: no
               ghostscript: no
                     latex: no
                   pdftops: no

    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                      dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    ============================================================================
                            * The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype, png
                            * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packa
                            * ges/freetype.htm for instructions to install
                            * freetype
                            * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packa
                            * ges/libpng.htm for instructions to install png
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

It's the same problem as here:
[Matplotlib install issues. Pip Centos - Freetype "Missing" when it is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076553/matplotlib-install-issues-pip-centos-freetype-missing-when-it-is-installed)

However I'm on Windows so that solution doesn't work.

I believe the solution is saying that this user need to install the freetype development headers, are these the same as the "sources," ie the optional part of installing freetype? If so, I have downloaded them but have no idea where to put them. There's `manifest` and `src` directories.

Comment: You would need to compile these libraries and then make the result detectable by the compiler. But how about making your life easier: The githun repo has `matplotlib=2.2.2` as a requirement. For that version, whl files on pypi go up to python 3.7. Since you are using a venv for this project already (I am assuming from your `c:\programming\python\example programs\deepfake\venv\` folder), make  it a python 3.7 venv. Then the matplotlib installation will not have to be from source

Comment: Thanks, using a python3.7 venv bypassed that error. Though now I am getting another error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt...

Comment: torch is only available for 64 bit python (at least from pypi, not sure about other sources), but you have 32 bit

Comment: Ah thanks. Got it all working now!

Answer (score 2):

Installing libfontconfig1-dev as per https://github.com/r-lib/systemfonts/issues/50#issue-706648329

```
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1-dev
```

did take me pass this!

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments by FlyingTeller. Solution was to just use a Python 3.7 64-bit venv.